# Node.js as an application container

Tags: node.js

Apache and Node.js have something in common.  The more I use Node.js, the more I like Node.js; similarly, more I use Apache, the more I like Node.js.

One good thing about Apache though, it can do a lot of things through the same port.   PHP, Python, Perl, different apps, different paths, the whole magilla.  Node.js doesn't do that, and it isn't supposed to but I would like to do something similar.

I would like to give it a list of URL-prefixes (or regexps ideally) and enough information to, if it receives a request matching a particular prefix, it passes off the request to a subordinate instance running a specified script (and it will start such an instance if it hasn't already, and close it down when doing so seems prudent).  Basically, I want `nodejs-proxy` and `cluster` cooperating.  With it, I could run several apps together on the same machine through port 80.

This seems pretty easy and very useful and I was about to just write it myself when it occurred to me, "This seems pretty easy and very useful -- probably someone has already written it!"  Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 classic. "The more I use apache, the more I like node.js"

Comment: Mongrel2 can be used to route requests like you want (if I understand correctly) and there are bindings for Node.  It is not Node software though.

Comment: @Austin -- that's looks like it would work, but I do want a Node module (a "nodule"?).  It's my belief that it is possible to construct a complex, highly efficient system entirely from Javascript and I wish to test this belief.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js doesn’t have any built-in ability to route requests to different applications, but frameworks like this are in development.

Nodejitsu’s [Haibu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/haibu) comes to mind — it manages child processes for each application and uses [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to route the requests.

Comment: @Miss.Code Feel free!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at http://expressjs.com which I describe as a 'sinatra for node'. It gives the whole URL/pattern based routing thing. You can couple this with https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource to create a kinda RESTful style resource approach.

Comment: Are you sure?  I looked through the docs and it seems the routing is to internal functions, not to other Nodes, which is very very different.

Comment: I guess this was me interpreting "it passes off the request to a subordinate instance" as "routing the request to a thread in which you can anything with it" rather than "if necessary start up a new node process to deal with the request". That's where I would look at god + nginx + a request queue for loadbalancing rather than writing something from scratch. YMMV. Relevant link: http://blog.acmarques.com/deploying_node_with_nginx_and_god

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you're looking for an event-based HTTP proxy (to replace Apache) - in that regard, [nginx](http://nginx.org/) seem to be current king of the hill.

Comment: Are you sure?  It doesn't look like it will maintain child processes to service those requests it proxies.

Comment: @Malvolio Many people use nginx as a *reverse proxy* to distribute requests to separate node.js instances.

Comment: @Sidnicious -- thanks, but my question is, will it *maintain* (i.e., start up and if advisable, shut down) those node.js instances.  If it won't, I will have to build a node.js program that will, and that program might well do the proxy-ing too; if it *will* [does happy dance].

Comment: @Malvolio I just posted an answer with a link to [Haibu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/haibu). It's a framework that does exactly this. It be what you're looking for, otherwise it might provide some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dokku](https://github.com/intermine/dokku) ([Docker](https://www.docker.io/) based) which will spawn your apps and provide a reverse proxy via nginx. Containers are isolated, you have a choice of buildpacks and your deployments have 0 downtime all by pushing repos via git and auth via ssh.

You can follow this easy [guide on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-node-js-app) on how to deploy your Node.js apps or just [watch the guide](http://progrium.com/blog/2013/06/19/dokku-the-smallest-paas-implementation-youve-ever-seen/) from the man himself.